# Using jQuery to calculate date from given months

Tags: jquery

I have a date variable in jQuery , I want to add number of months to it and get the final date
using it

```
var warranty = $.trim(response);   // 24, that is number of months of warranty
var dt1 = $.trim(response);    // retuns a string 2013-09-28
var diff = new Date(dt );   // days Sat Sep 28 2013 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard time)
```

I want the date, the warranty finishes, how can I get it?

Comment: here `warranty` and `dt1` having same value but as per comment it should be different, right?

Comment: no, warranty value is the number of months of warranty of a product, that is 24 or 36, dt1 value is the date of installation of the product, that is 2013-09-28. I have to calculate the date the warranty finishes

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
diff.setMonth(diff.getMonth() + parseInt(warranty));
```